# Add css class to individual tags in Rails with acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Using the acts_as_taggable_on works great.  But generates a comma separated list.  I'm wondering the best way to add a wrapper element and class to each individually.  I've been able to do it in jQuery, but I'd much rather do it in a rails helper.

ie.

```
item.tags = "big, bigger, biggest"
item.tag_list = ["big", "bigger", "biggest"]
```

to render as:

```
<span class="tag">big</span>
<span class="tag">bigger</span>
<span class="tag">biggest</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a helper that can generate a list of spans based on the tag_list sent in.

```
def tags(tag_list)
  markup = ""
  tag_list.each do |tag|
    markup += content_tag(:span, tag, :class => "tag")
  end
  raw(markup)
end
```

You would then call it with:

```
<%= tags(item.tag_list) %>
```

which will output

```
<span class="tag">tag 1</span>
<span class="tag">tag 2</span>
<span class="tag">tag 3</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a cleaner way of doing it without creating a new function and keeping the code in the view:

```
<% @item.tag_counts_on(:tags).map(&:name).each do |tag| %>
   <a href="/search/<%= tag %>">
    <span class="tag"><%= tag %></span>
   </a>
<% end %>
```